# SolrCloud Collection API returns Bad Request

Tags: solrcloud

I was trying to get the status of SolrCloud cluster by issuing something like below:

```
http://mysolrcloud:8983/solr/admin/collections?wt=json&action=CLUSTERSTATUS
```

But I got the 400 Bad Request and when I looked at the log file, I found the following error:

```
Unknown action: CLUSTERSTATUS
```

Is my request path wrong or do I need to register some handler in solr.xml or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This operation was released in Solr 4.8.0. What version of Solr are you running?

Comment: Really? I think I found documentation from 4.6 or lower and tried but didn't work. Anywya it is good to know that